# Array Formula, Concatenate, and If Function in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas

I have a formula to nicely format some data I need to combine.

```
=IF(ArrayFormula(Isblank(Z2:AA2)), Y2, IF(Isblank(AA2), CONCATENATE(Y2, " ", "|", " ", Z2), CONCATENATE(Y2, " ", "|", " ", Z2, " ", "|", " ", AA2)))
```

How do I get this to automatically copy when a new row is added? Data comes from a google form, so new rows will be added periodically, and I need this formula to be added to each new row. I tried adding arrayformula at the beginning, but got an error that it will overwrite data in the column to the right. Thank you in advance!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Z2:Z="")*(AA2:AA=""), Y2:Y,
 IF(AA2:AA="", Y2:Y&" | "&Z2:Z,  Y2:Y&" | "&Z2:Z&" | "&AA2:AA)))
```